# Checkout a tag in headless state with JGit

Tags: jgit

Attempting to use JGit to checkout an existing tag on an existing repository. Preferably left in a headless state. The command should be as simple as:

```
git checkout clever-tag-name
```

However, the JGit incantation:

```java
String tagName = "clever-tag-name";
Git.open(new File(repoPath)).checkout().setName(tagName).call();
```

Results in a series of checkout errors. This usage seems like it should be trivial. The command line version has no issues given my repo's current state.

Here's an example of the checkout error I am referring to:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.CheckoutConflictException: Checkout conflict with files: 
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
...
at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.doCheckout(DirCacheCheckout.java:416)
at org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCacheCheckout.checkout(DirCacheCheckout.java:397)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:261)
... 6 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code looks good. What are the 'checkout errors' exactly? Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Just updated post with an example. Trouble is, there are no such conflicts with the traditional command. I would have expected something like this from checking out a branch with pending changes; but this is a clean repo.

Comment: Just a guess, are you running on Windows and the core.filemode  config setting is set to true? If you run git.status().call() just before the checkout code, does it report 'clean'?

Comment: Nope. OSX v10.9.5. Running the status snippet, interestingly enough I'm now seeing the set of files from the original error! I'm curious why `git status` versus this incantation is distinct. To be precise, I'm performing `git.status().call().getUncommittedChanges()`

Comment: Is there anything particular about these files (.gitignored, .gitattributed)? Are you on the exact same repository (`git.getRepository().getDirectory() / getWorkTree()`)? If `git status` and `git.status()` yield different results on the same repository it is probably a bug. In this case you might want to [ask the JGit mailing list or report a bug](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/support/).

Comment: Could it be that the files simply are changed locally and would also change by the checkout?

Comment: Could it be that the files simply are changed locally and would also change by the checkout?

Comment: Nothing odd about those files from what I can tell. And just checked the code snippets recommended. Both refer to the same repository.

Comment: Lastly, I'm certain the repo is clean as each time prior I've run a `git clean -dxf` manually

Comment: Will try to reach out to the JGit mailing list and see what turns out. Again, thanks for the replies!